# Translating TextView into SpannableString

Tags: android, animation, translation

I have a screen where the user is selecting a keyword then that keyword is highlighted in next screen inside a sentence which is done by `SpannableString`.

What I want is to animate selected keyword to it's place in `SpannableString`.

Is it possible to animate a `TextView`'s text inside a `SpannableString`'s text?

Comment: yes it is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, don't think of it as "animate a `TextView's` text inside a `SpannableString's` text". Think of it as "animate one `TextView` to another `TextView`".

Generally that's a pretty painful thing to implement. There are thousands of way to do that, but the best one is described by [`Nick Butcher` in his `Animatable` talk](https://youtu.be/86p1GPEv_fY?t=944).